# How to return an error message when connecting to my sql database useing jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post

I am trying to return an error using jquery post function to retrieve the error.

So far I have written in php

`$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("Error connecting to the database.");`

but i want to retunrn the message like so

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

if(!$connect){              
  $data['error'] = true;
  $data['message'] = "Error connecting to the database.";
  echo json_encode($data);  
};
```

Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => mysql_error())));
```

This will encode the error to a json string

Comment: Perfect I edited to suit `$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Could not connect to database.'))); `

Comment: MySQL error is also good to send, as it will help a lot for debugging (unless you log it some other way, or are on a production site).